# Using Cauchy's formula for derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be an analytic function in $X$ such that $|f(z)|\leq Me^{c|z|}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$ Use the Cauchy formula for derivatives to prove that $|f'(z)| \leq ceMe^{c|z|}$

I'm stumped. My first thoughts were to use the fact that if $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C},$ $\bar{S}(\alpha,\rho)$ is in $X$, $f$ analytic in X and $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $\alpha$ in the boundary of $S(\alpha,\rho)$, then $$|f^{(n)}(\alpha)| \leq M\frac {n!}{\rho}$$

but I'm not quite sure how to use this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let's say it was. Would that make a difference in the approach I should be taking to prove this with Cauchy's formula?

Comment: There are no restrictions on $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write from [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)

$$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z')}{(z'-z)^2}\,dz' \tag 1$$

Now, we apply $(1)$ by choosing the contour $C$ to be a circle of radius $r$ with center at $z$.  Then, we have the following set of upper bounds for $f'$.

$$\begin{align}
|f'(z)|&\le\frac{1}{2\pi }\oint_C\frac{|f(z')|}{|z'-z|^2}\,d|z'|\\\\
&\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C\frac{Me^{c|z'|}}{|z-z'|^2}\,d|z'|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{Me^{c|z+re^{i\theta}|}}{r^2}\,r\,d\theta\\\\
&\le \frac{Me^{c|z|}e^{cr}}{r} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Note that the value for $r$ for which the right-hand side of $(2)$ is a minimum is $r=1/c$.  Thus, for all real-valued $r$, the right-hand side is at least

$$\frac{Me^{c|z|}e^{c\times \frac1c}}{\frac1c}=ceMe^{c|z|}$$

Therefore, we have

$$|f'(z)|\le ceMe^{c|z|}$$

as was to be shown!